# Plotly express scatter - how to force each curve to have a unique color?

Tags: scatter-plot, plotly-python

When using plotly express for scatter chart, eventually (after 10 items) two of those will have the same color. is it possible to increase the default color discrete map ?

I tried to add a symbol to differentiate btw two similar color but by default, plotly express would pick the same color and the same symbol for two different items.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a color sequence that has 26 different colors, would that be enough? Other options are shown here https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/#color-sequences-in-plotly-express.  In example using the Alphabet scale in image below, the colors start to repeat at Comoros.

```py
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder()
fig = px.line(df, y="lifeExp", x="year", color="country",
             color_discrete_sequence=px.colors.qualitative.Alphabet,
             title="Alphabet color sequence")

fig.show()
```

[image]